# Laravel searching through relationships

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've tried to get help on this question before but I think people are either misinterpreting my question or don't quite understand what I'm trying to achieve, with Eloquent / Laravel.

Each user has many categories. Each category has many articles. 
I want to retrieve all the articles from a set of categories which the user has.

So say a user has category 1, category 2, I want to retrieve all articles from category 1 and category 2.

For each of these belongsToMany relationships below, I have my own pivot tables.

article_categories

id  |   articleID   |   categoryId

users_cats

id  |   user_details_id          |      categories_id

Relationships.

**Articles.php**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'article_categories', 'articleID', 'categoryID');
}
```

**UserDetails.php**

```
public function Categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Categories', 'users_cats', 'user_details_id', 'categories_id');
}
```

**Categories.php**

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article', 'article_categories', 'categoryID', 'articleID');
}

public function UserDetails()
{
    return $this->HasMany('App\UserDetails', 'users_cats', 'user_details_id', 'categories_id');
}
```

I have tried to use HasMany through but It doesn’t work with a many to many relationship as far as I can tell.

Currently (as a sort of “work around”) I've been using this. I've pulled up a list of the user's Categories and searching through all of ids and pulling the relevant Article and forming a collection from it in UserDetails.php

```
$user = self::find($this->id);
$user = $user->Categories;

foreach ($user as $item) {
    foreach ($item->articles as $article)
        $article1[] = Article::find($article->id);
}

$articles = collect($article1)->sortByDesc('date')->unique();

return $articles;
```

However I don’t think it will scale well with increasing data (it's already producing over 1k queries with only 1000 articles, taking over 8 seconds to load).

Any ideas?

Comment: Just wondering why are you doing self::find? Instead of injecting an instance of the User model?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a function,with this:

```
public function User_all_artical($id){
        $aricles=DB::table('articles') //open articles table
                    ->join('categories',function($join) use ($id)){ //join to categories table
                        $join->on('articles.categoryID','=','categories.id')//where from articles table the categoryID column === categories table ID column
                             ->where('categories.userID',$id); //where categories have user id ==$id
                    }
                    ->get();

    }
```

Comment: Im getting confused with where should be in category_table.id_user. 

I have my categories in a table called categories, each has an id. 
I have all my articles in journalarticles, each has an id.

should it be `->where('categories.user_details_id',$id)`? How does it know to use the pivot table

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nested eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
$user=User::with('categories.articles')->find(1);
foreach($user->categories as $category)
{
    echo $category->name;
    forech($category->articles as $article)
    {
       echo $article->name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Produces the same / longer load time. Im using this. 


    `public function getUserArticles(){
        $user=\App\UserDetails::with('categories.articles')->find($this->id);

        foreach($user->categories as $category) {
            echo $category->category;
            foreach ($category->articles as $article) {
                $articlescol[] = $article;
            }
        }
        return collect($articlescol)->sortByDesc('date')->unique();
    }`

Comment: @user5067291 why are you putting `$article` in array and making it collection? and then sorting by date? state what are you trying to acheive.

Comment: I want to retrieve a collection of articles based on the categories which the user has in order to pass to the blade.

Order the collection by Date. Have no repeats.

Comment: all you require is $article. use constraing eager load to order the articles by date and to get distinct articles. $article is itseld an object of collection. putting into array and then again making a collection doesnot make sense. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I don't get what you mean when you say all you require is $article. I can use the constraining eager loading in order to order  / get distinct values granted but how do I pull the collection of articles from the $user variable as `$user->categories->articles` returns undefined property. 

I need a big list of articles from all user categories.

Comment: I mean `$category->articles` is a collection of articles you need.

Comment: With an eager loading do you need to run the foreach command to access the elements of the foreach first?

I currently have this ->

`

        $user=\App\UserDetails::with(['categories.articles' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('date', 'desc');

        }])->find(1);
        
        foreach($user->categories as $category)
        {}

        return $category->articles->unique();`

Answer (score 0):

You could add the following to your `UserDetails` model:

```
public function articles()
{
    return $this->Categories()->getRelated()->articles()->getRelated()
        ->whereHas('Categories', function ($query) {
            $query->whereHas('UserDetails', function ($query) {
                $query->where('id', $this->id);
            });
        });
}
```

This way you can then do:

```
$user->articles()->orderBy('date', 'desc')->get();
```

Hope this helps!